# Does it cost a spell slot to cast a spell from a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spell-slots

If you have to use a spell slot to put a spell into the *ring of spell storing*, do you again have to spend a slot to cast a spell from the ring?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, someone already spent a spell slot (or slots) by filling up the slot(s) in the ring

> Ring of Spell Storing Ring,
>   *rare (requires attunement)*
>
> This ring stores *spells cast into it*, holding them until the attuned
>   wearer uses them. The ring can  store up to 5 levels worth of spells
>   at a time. When found, it contains 1d6 − 1 levels of stored  spells
>   chosen by the GM.
>   *Any creature can cast a spell* of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring *as the spell is cast*.   (SRD, v5.1, p. 237)

I italicized "cast into it" and "as the spell is cast" as a link to basic rules on spell casting.

> When a character *casts a spell*, he or she expends a slot of that
>   spell’s level or higher, effectively “filling” a slot with the spell. ([Basic Rules, p. 82](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=82))

As an example: a Fighter (Champion) can cast a stored spell from this ring without even having spell slots from their class (they have no spell slots), once they are attuned to the ring that has spells already stored in it.

For what it's worth, [we have a lot of related questions on the Ring of Spell storing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D%20spell%20storing).  You may find them all of interest, since it's a very versatile item.  My first D&D group [applied this approach](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104249/22566) to provide familiars for multiple characters by using the ring.

To answer your comment:

> So I can cast spells into it, then change my prepared spells and have
>   a wider range of spells ready.

Yes, that is a way to use it (preparation).  Think of it as a wallet.  You put some cash into it and you can go and spend the cash while shopping.  Then it's empty.  You have to put some more cash into it to fill it up before the next shopping trip.

Comment: So it sounds like you have to use a spell slot to use a spell stored.

Comment: So I can cast spells into it, then change my prepared spells and have a wider range of spells ready.

Comment: @JDAvery As to your first comment: I don't see how you drew that conclusion.  You have to use a spell slot to store a spell.  Retrieving a spell is free, and can be done by anybody, even if they don't *have* spell slots. (Provided they are attuned.)

Comment: @JDAvery no. Is a storage device. You cast a spell into the ring, and the ring stores it until you need it.