# Can a spell storing ring give a whole party Greater steeds?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

This came up in a game the other night, it seems broken but I can't find anything that says it's not allowed.

A party member has "Find Greater steed" and casts it into a spell storing ring. Another party member then attunes, casts from the ring, and has their own Pegasus.

Repeat for the whole party and now they all have their own Pegasus to ride, until they dismiss it/it dies.

Obviously this assumes they have time to repeatedly re-attune and regain spell slots, but still seems a little OP. Have I missed something?

Comment: Related: [How does a ring of spell storing function?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76556/how-does-a-ring-of-spell-storing-function), [Can my familiar use a ring of spell storing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70692/can-my-familiar-use-a-ring-of-spell-storing), [How does Find Familiar work with a ring of spell storing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104249/how-does-find-familiar-work-with-a-ring-of-spell-storing), [Endless Menagerie](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148416/can-a-ring-of-spell-storing-and-access-to-find-spells-produce-an-endless-menager)

Comment: How many people are in the party?

Answer (score 2):

### It’s a Ring of Spell Storing - they *are* OP

This works. So do lots of other OP things - [familiars all round for example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104249/22566).

Comment: It may be worth pointing out just how long this would actually take (80 minutes per steed summoning, each using a 4th level slot, and then also probably long rests to regain spell slots). They'd also already be level 13 (or have a Bard who took this with Magical Secrets at level 10).

Comment: @Medix2 time is so rarely a scarce resource, it hardly matters